# How to run 2 loops simultaneously in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am very new in writing code, so it might be a silly question, but an answer is highly appreciated to enhance my learning. I have written a simple bash script as below. But how can I optimize this code by using loop, array? I can understand if I use two loops, I can make the lines of code shorter. Please help:

```
#!/bin/bash

zs=10.0.3.10
zb=/usr/local/bin/zabbix_sender
zh=zabbix

# ql1 = queue link

ql1=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/843390035802/testService1

val1=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url $ql1 --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --region us-west-2 --output text | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$ql1 count is $val1"
    $zb -z $zs -s $zh -k testService1 -o val1 >/dev/null 2>&1


ql2=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/853390078801/testService2

val2=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url $ql2 --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --region us-west-2 --output text | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$ql2 count is $val2"
    $zb -z $zs -s $zh -k testService2 -o val2 >/dev/null 2>&1


ql3=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/843393305801/testService3

val3=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url $ql3 --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --region us-west-2 --output text | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$ql3 count is $val3"
    $zb -z $zs -s $zh -k testService3 -o val3 >/dev/null 2>&1


ql4=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/875660005801/testService4

val4=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url $ql4 --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --region us-west-2 --output text | awk '{print $2}')
 echo "$ql4 count is $val4"
    $zb -z $zs -s $zh -k testService4 -o val4 >/dev/null 2>&1


ql5=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/843390635802/testService5

val5=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url $ql5 --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --region us-west-2 --output text | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$ql5 count is $val5"
    $zb -z $zs -s $zh -k testService2 -o val5 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

In above code at this step
`$zb -z $zs -s $zh -k testService2 -o val5 >/dev/null 2>&1` I used `-k` as different 5 values. So how can I arrange it and work the code as same as above?

Comment: Are you using real URLs ? If so, I'd advise you to delete your question and post it back with dummy values

Comment: no these are not real URLS, i customized it for posting purpose.

Comment: You meant `testService5` rather than `testService2` in the last line, didn't you?

Comment: How do you want the five command sequences to run - in parallel, or one after the other?

Comment: Why do you think of two loops? One loop is sufficient to eliminate the code duplication.

Comment: You mean `-o $val…` rather than `-o val…` in the `$zb` command, don't you?

Comment: I suggest you play around with `eval`. It can be used to work around not knowing how to do a lot of stuff. Your code, though, just needs one loop that uses an array. You can google `bash arrays`.

Comment: @Armali -o $val it will be like this. you are correct. I want to finish this code within below lines. Not using same line for every link and -k "Value"

ql1=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/843390035802/testService1

val1=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url $ql1 --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --region us-west-2 --output text | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$ql1 count is $val1"
    $zb -z $zs -s $zh -k testService1 -o val1 >/dev/null 2>&1

If i use just one array i can get my result but I am unable to arrange it with  "-k testService1"

Comment: @HappyFace thank you for your suggestion. I will look into eval.

Answer (score 0):

One loop is sufficient to eliminate the code duplication, and we don't need an array - we can read one *queue link* after the other in the loop. The variable argument to the option `-k` can be extracted from the *queue link* by removing the URL part up to to last `/` with the [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${parameter##word}`.

```
zs=10.0.3.10
zb=/usr/local/bin/zabbix_sender
zh=zabbix
# ql = queue link
while read ql
do
    val=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url $ql --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --region us-west-2 --output text | awk '{print $2}')
    echo "$ql count is $val"
    $zb -z $zs -s $zh -k ${ql##*/} -o $val >/dev/null 2>&1
done <<END
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/843390035802/testService1
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/853390078801/testService2
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/843393305801/testService3
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/875660005801/testService4
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/843390635802/testService5
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check on it and give you my feedback. thank you so much for your effort.